# How do I change date to continuous numbers in R?

Tags: r, date

so I have a dataframe with date and ranks of three tennis players. I want to convert the dates to continuous days so that 2001-01-01 is 0.

I tried this:

```
days <- yday(x) - 1 # so Jan 1 = day 0 
total_days <- cumsum(days)
```

It does do the job but only per year so for 2002 it starts over, again in 2003, and so on.

I would very much appreciate some help with this.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract days from `'2001-01-01'` to get number of days since that date.

```
x <- as.Date(c('2001-04-03', '2002-02-01'))
total_days <- as.numeric(x - as.Date('2001-01-01'))
total_days

#[1]  92 396
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also convert to `integer` first and subtract

```
 as.integer(x) - as.integer(as.Date('2001-01-01'))
[1]  92 396
```

#### data

```
x <- as.Date(c('2001-04-03', '2002-02-01'))
```